# Image URL on fastreport

Tags: fastreport

Good evening,

Is there a way to display an image via url in fastreport? I have tried several solutions from the internet but to no avail

I tried on filelink but without success, the version is 4

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but we recently made a report that contains a picture which is loaded from a hyperlink.
We added 1 line of code to the StartReport event.

```
private void _StartReport(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Assign URL from dataset to picture
  PictureMapbox.ImageLocation = ((String)Report.GetColumnValue("OrderHeader.MapURL"));
}
```

The function `_StartReport` is attached to the `StartReport` event in the properties of the report itself.
That should do the trick.